# Any ideas on how this iPad interface was made?

Tags: ios, ipad

Warner Bros was published a year ago a promo iPad application for the movie "SHERLOCK HOLMES: A GAME OF SHADOWS". The app is free and one can download it here: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sherlock-holmes-game-shadows/id515031420?mt=8

I think that the interface of it is brilliant (with the parallax scrolling and the fade in/ fadeouts of the background photos etc) and a similar interface would be very suitable for an app I am planning to design.

I would like to ask if you have any idea on what tools they might have used to create it (e.g. is it scroll views one on top of another, is it cocoa2d).

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: It's hard to say looking at the end result, but it could be HTML5 as suggested by Deusdies, it could be Cocos2d, or more likely and simply it could just be custom UI elements like scroll views and buttons with a lot of photoshop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's HTML 5. Maybe something like [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/).